# How to dynamically create queues in Springboot for websocket messaging

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, messagebroker

I'm using websockets to build a chat server in springboot. Now my application lacks any kind of Spring Security information since it is intended to only act as a channel between two desktop clients. 
So currently I'm able to broadcast messages to all clients, however, I would like to know, is it possible to create dynamic queues when a client connects to other user, (a queue is created and they both subscribe to same queue). The queue exists until one of the client disconnects.
I'm using SimpleMessageBroker priovided with Spring.